# Payment gate way in in prestashop1.7.3

Tags: prestashop, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.7

I added a payment plugin to pestashop 1.7.3
The plugin is working perfect in the BackOffice but it's not among the active payment modules and it is not showing up on the checkout process.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What have you tried so far and can you give us examples?

Comment: for the module is a payment gate way module, a bank gave it to me but after I installed the module and configure it it shows that it's working perfectly in the back office, but when it came to the active payment it's not there, due to that my customers can't see it between the payment choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked "payment">"preferences" and "shop perameters">"customer settings">"groups" to make sure your new gateway is enabled and available to all groups?

Comment: yes, I checked it, the module is enable there, but the problem that the module is not in the active payment page, so it's not showing in my web site

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your installed module configuration page? or at least a list of all the settings there and the current value for each? Sounds like you are saying the module shows up in your installed module list, but not in the backend active payment list

Comment: Well, thank you so much for your help, the problem wasn't in prestashop, but it was on the version of the module I used. The probleme was solved when I got provided with last version of the module.